# How to access singleton class object in extended class

Tags: php, object, singleton, this

Plz tell me where i'm doing wrong...

I've 3 classes. These are like this..

1. Singleton class where i'm following singleton design pattern
2. Class ram
3. Class sam

In 'ram' class i'm setting data for singleton class object.

Now, in 'sam' class.. i'm trying to access singleton class object inside show_data() function of sam class.

When, i'm using..

```
Print_r($this) : showing empty object
```

but, when  i'm using following code..

```
$singleton_obj = Singleton::getInstance();
print_r($singleton_obj); : Showing content of singleton object
```

**My question is,** 
why in-case of **Print_r($this)** it's showing empty object. Is there any way, i can get content of singleton class object by using **Print_r($this)**.

**MY class file is this..**

```
<?php 
class Singleton
{
 // A static property to hold the single instance of the class
private static $instance;

// The constructor is private so that outside code cannot instantiate
public function __construct() { }

// All code that needs to get and instance of the class should call
// this function like so: $db = Database::getInstance();
public function getInstance()
{
  // If there is no instance, create one
  if (!isset(self::$instance)) {
    $c = __CLASS__;
    self::$instance = new $c;
  }
  return self::$instance;
}

// Block the clone method
private function __clone() {}


// Function for inserting data to object
public function insertData($param, $element)
{
$this->{$param} = $element;
}
}

//---CLASS ram---
class ram
{
    function __construct() 
    {
        $db = Singleton::getInstance();
        $db->insertData('name', 'Suresh');
    }
}

$obj_ram = new ram;

//---CLASS sam---
class sam extends Singleton
{
    function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct();
   }

   public function show_data()
   {
    echo "<br>Data in current object<br>";
    print_r($this);

    echo "<br><br>Data in singleton object<br>";
        $singleton_obj = Singleton::getInstance();
        print_r($singleton_obj);
   } 
}

$obj_sam = new sam;
echo $obj_sam->show_data(); 
?>
```

Comment: If your insertData function you have an extra }, at least in the code here not sure if that's just a typo or if it exists in your code.

Comment: why getInstance isn't a static method?

Comment: Your comment says __construct() is `private` but your code declares it public?

Comment: @Laxus is it need to be static? I've not a deep OOP's knowledge of PHP. By the way, even if i changed that to static it's not making any effect.

Comment: Your code is behaving as expected. You should not try to extend Singletons. That's not how the pattern is used. You want only one instance of the Singleton - no cloning or children.

Comment: @adityamenon Hey, i've not using any private constructor in my singleton class. Look my code.. which i've given in top.

Comment: @frosty That extra } is closing braces of singleton class.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are creating a "`sam`" object by "`new sam`", you sould use "`sam::getInstance()`"; to reach the static instance but it won't be "sam object" type will be "Singleton" "."**__*CLASS*__**" gives the scope class not the real object class.

**First**: you must read about "[late static binding](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.late-static-bindings.php)" in php and learn the limitations of self:: and **__*CLASS*__**  use "`static::`" instead of "`self::`" (5.3+)

Or you can change all the pattern use statics like;

```
   <?php 
    class Singleton
    {
        // A static property to hold the single instance of the class
        private static $instance;

        // The constructor is private so that outside code cannot instantiate
        public function __construct() { }

        // All code that needs to get and instance of the class should call
        // this function like so: $db = Database::getInstance();
        public static function getInstance()
        {
            // If there is no instance, create one
            if (!isset(self::$instance)) {
                $c = __CLASS__;
                self::$instance = new $c;
            }
            return self::$instance;
        }

        // Block the clone method
        private function __clone() {}


        // Function for inserting data to object
        public function insertData($param, $element)
        {
            $this->{$param} = $element;
        }
    }

    //---CLASS ram---
    class ram
    {
        function __construct() 
        {
            $db = Singleton::getInstance();
            $db->insertData('name', 'Suresh');
        }
    }

    $obj_ram = new ram;

    //---CLASS sam---
    class sam extends Singleton
    {
        function __construct()
        {
            parent::__construct();
        }

        public static function show_data()
        {
            echo "<br>Data in current object<br>";
            print_r(self::getInstance());
            echo "<br><br>Data in singleton object<br>";
            $singleton_obj = Singleton::getInstance();
            print_r($singleton_obj);
        } 
    }

$obj_sam = sam::getInstance();
print_r($obj_sam);

    echo sam::show_data();
```

This is an example which setting the properties pointers to the current object like "CI"

```
<?php 
    class Singleton
    {
        // A static property to hold the single instance of the class
        private static $instance;

        // The constructor is private so that outside code cannot instantiate
        public function __construct() {

            if(isset(self::$instance))
                foreach(self::$instance as $key => &$val)
                {
                    $this->{$key} = &$val;
            }
        }



        // All code that needs to get and instance of the class should call
        // this function like so: $db = Database::getInstance();
        public static function getInstance()
        {
            // If there is no instance, create one
            if (!isset(self::$instance)) {
                $c = __CLASS__;
                self::$instance = new $c;
            }
            return self::$instance;
        }

        // Block the clone method
        private function __clone() {}


        // Function for inserting data to object
        public function insertData($param, $element)
        {
            $this->{$param} = $element;
        }
    }

    //---CLASS ram---
    class ram
    {
        function __construct() 
        {
            $db = Singleton::getInstance();
            $db->insertData('name', 'Suresh');
        }
    }

     class ram2
    {
        function __construct() 
        {
            $db = Singleton::getInstance();
            $db->insertData('name', 'Suresh');
            $db->insertData('name2', 'Suresh2');
        }
    }

    $obj_ram = new ram;
    $obj_ram = new ram2;

    //---CLASS sam---
    class sam extends Singleton
    {
        function __construct()
        {
            parent::__construct();
        }

        public function show_data()
        {
            echo "<br>Data in current object<br>";
            print_r($this);

            echo "<br><br>Data in singleton object<br>";
            $singleton_obj = Singleton::getInstance();
            print_r($singleton_obj);
        } 
    }

    $obj_sam = new sam;
    echo $obj_sam->show_data();
```

Comment: Hey, thanks a lot for helping me by showing exact code. This is really helpful. 

Can u tell me, is there any mechanistic by which in show_data() of 'sam' class.. i can get all the data of singleton object by using $this.

Ex : print_r($this) : // Should give all singleton object data

Comment: if you want to use "$this" you must write your code into Singleton class because the type of "$instance" is "Singleton".  Why arent you using "Singleton::getInstnace()" if you want the Singleton object properties?

Comment: Hey, I'm not so good in PHP OOP's. Can u help me by showing some code. I mean, what.. exactly i need to write in singleton class. So that, in in show_data() of 'sam' class i can get those data by $this.

Comment: Hey, I think u r familiar with codeigniter.  I just want the same way like CI do. From any controller class by using $this i need to access all data of singleton object.

Comment: Static properties cannot be accessed through the object using the arrow operator ->. So $this can not help you about that. If you want to access this instance through . You dont need to "sam" class. Use Singleton directly

Comment: Read the Code of Core-Controller.php https://github.com/EllisLab/CodeIgniter/blob/develop/system/core/Controller.php It's getting the static instance and rebuild the object after in constructor method (damn!) and now, i wil re-write your code wait.

Comment: I added a new example (like CI) end of the my answer.

Comment: Thanks a lot. It'll really help me a lot to understand this. I know how to work with CI but never tried to see the underneath code. This is the first time, i'm digging inside of CI code & i got stucked at here.

Thanks again for helping a lot.

Answer (score 0):

Your singleton is not getting 'initialized' - it does not create any object. So `$this` is referring to nothing.

EDIT: Turns out I'm wrong - I've usually seen Singletons declare __construct() as `private`. That's how new instances of the class are denied from being instantiated. Not sure what's going on in your case though.

EDIT 2: What is the problem? Your code behaves as expected. You're creating a new `sam` with no data in it, so you are getting an empty object. And when you print the singleton object, you are seeing the Singleton's data.

EDIT 3: I've never seen Singletons being extended. I think that's the wrong application of the pattern, I might be wrong of course.

Comment: @adiya menon
By this code i'm intializing singleton..

//---CLASS ram---
class ram
{
    function __construct() 
    {
        $db = Singleton::getInstance();
        $db->insertData('name', 'Suresh');
    }
}

    $obj_ram = new ram;

Comment: Hey, i want the singleton class object in my $this pointer. So, whenever i use   Print_r($this).. i can get all data of singleton object.

Comment: You need to read up on this matter my friend, this is a wrong approach.

Comment: Hey, have u seen codeigniter framework of PHP. They use same technique. They've a main singleton controller class & they extend that class in other controller class. 

I'm just trying to emulate that technique but.. don't know where i'm doing wrong.

Comment: Yep, just went and had a look at CI's code, I don't understand what's happening there either, looks like a question I'm going to learn something from :) good luck!

Answer (score 0):

You can't access static properties of class from within that class object.

`A property declared as static can not be accessed with an instantiated class object (though a static method can).`

http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.static.php